# Is it possible to include SPM checkouts in Git?

Tags: xcode, xcode11, swift-package-manager

It's possible to store Checkout and Build directories when using CocoaPods and Carthage.

Is this possible using Xcode 11's SPM?

Or, if I could modify the location SPM uses for Checkouts, then I think this could work by setting this directory to somewhere in the workspace's directory structure.

(I'm in the camp that prefers to keep all assets required to build projects in the same Git repo as the project itself. Don't hate me :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

See my previous response to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58105335/6900902).