# Swift Package Manager - How to add checkouts to source control?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

By default SPM downloads packaged code to derived data folder. I would like to commit those to my project repository. Is there any way to do it?

I have some security concerns for downloading packages source code every time I need to build project on new machine. How can I be sure that the code that SPM will download will be exactly the same code every time? What if package's repository is compromised and malicious code in included?
When using Cocoapods I can be sure that any remote machine is building exactly the same code that I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save packages downloaded by SPM into project GIT using Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57819160/save-packages-downloaded-by-spm-into-project-git-using-xcode-11)

Comment: @Cristik I hoped that things changed in last 2 years since that question was asked. Unfortunately, it seems it is still not supported. Thank you.